# debugging azure errors: beginner

Tags: debugging, azure

Pls point me to good resources  to debug  beginner errors with azure. If it ok posting my simple queue service code for the web and worker role, I could do the same and  get some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting and Debugging in Windows Azure:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465380.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short article what helped me with debugging. You may want to have a short look here: [Debugging in Azure Cloud](http://codingsoul.de/2014/11/12/debugging-in-azure-cloud/)

In a nutshell: Find the correct processes to attach to for worker role and web role. WebRole: WaIISHost.exe, w3wp.exe + conhost(s) WorkerRole: WaWorkerHost.exe + conhost(s)